# Multiple CSV records into one Java Object

Tags: java, spring

This is my csv file.

```
id,firstname,lastname,email,profession
100,betyyy,Wandie,abc@gmail.com;java dev
100,betyyy,Wandie,abc@gmail.com;sql dev
100,betyyy,Wandie,abc@gmail.com;angular dev
101,Janey,Firmin,xyz@gmail.com,heart doctor
101,Janey,Firmin,xyz@gmail.com, eye doctor
102,Blinni,Olin,Blinni.Olin@gmail.com,firefighter
103,Julieta,Karna,Julieta.Karna@gmail.com,worker
```

I need to convert CSV records into Jav objects.The key is id column in csv i.e all csv records with same id will correspond to 1 Java object i.e they have differe "profession" values .eg for id=100 i need one java object.My person class looks like this

```
public class Person
{
public Integer id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;

    public  public String[] profession;


}
```

This is the code i have written but it is return one POJO for each CSV record.How do i fix the code to handle my scenario

```
File inputF = new File(inputFilePath);
            InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(inputF);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS));
            inputList = br
                    .lines()
                    .skip(1)
                    .map(this::mapToPerson)
                   // .filter( this::checkValidObject  )
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            br.close();

private  Person mapToPerson (String line)
    {
        String[] p = line.split(COMMA);// a CSV has comma separated lines
        Person person = new Person();

        person.setId( Integer.parseInt(p[0]));
        person.setFirstName(p[1]);
        person.setLastName(p[2]);
        person.setEmail(p[3]);
        person.setProfession(p[4]);
        return person;
}
```

Comment: Your code is creating a list of Persons, one for each line in your csv file. Is that not what you want?

Comment: By the way, you could simplify your file reading with `try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) { lines.skip(1)... } catch (IOException ex) { ... }`

Comment: i vant read your code

Comment: No i dont want a Person object for each line.i Want one Java obkject for each id

Comment: after collecting to the list, you can stream the list and use a groupBy collector, grouping by ID and then map each resulting list of person (e.g. 3 persons for id 100) to a single person with several professions

Comment: can i show the example..i can group by id but how to map the value of professions